# JNI pass by reference fails

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have the following code in Java:

```
class Foo {
   public native int bar(String name);

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Foo fo = new Foo();
     String n = "Name1";
     fo.(n);
     System.out.println(n);
   }
}
```

And in C I have:

```
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_ehsunbehravesh_j7_j7win_windows_Computer_getComputerName
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring name) {
      name = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Name2");  
      return 0;
    }
```

I assume the result on the screen should be `Name2` But it is `Name1`

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable. Why not just return it instead?

```
 public native String bar();

[..]

 JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_ehsunbehravesh_j7_j7win_windows_Computer_getComputerName
      (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
 {
     return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Name2");  
 }
```

Comment: I need to return an int value and I need to obey the standards of a library. So if I use character[] instead it will solve the problem???

Comment: I think you'll have to go into some more detail about what you're trying to accomplish. Could you add to your question a little?

Comment: The only thing I want to do is to manipulate a passed parameter in the C and access the new value in the Java because I can not return the value using `return` command. And the nature of the value is something like String or char[].

Answer (score 0):

In the C code, name is a local variable. Changing it will not change the string object to which it formerly pointed. In addition, java String's are immutable, so you can't change the object. What you could do would be to return the reference to a new String, since you're not using the integer return value.

Comment: I need to return an int value and I need to obey the standards of a library. So if I use character[] instead it will solve the problem???

Comment: You could use a char[] / jcharArray. See the JNI documentation on array operations. Note that a jchar is a short, not a C char.